# Backbone.js Views

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, view

Lets say I'm creating kind of a social network. On the one hand you can search for people which displays a list of profiles as a result; on the other hand you can click a 'my friends' button which also displays a list of profiles. So in both cases you get a list of profiles, but with slight differences, for example you dont have a 'make friend' button in the srcond list or any other difference in every list item.

My question is: Should I create in this case one view for both lists, for example 'listOfProfiles'? If yes, how do I deal with the dofferences or any further content I want to display in one of both? If not, why?

I know this is a general question. It's just that I'm new to backbone or MVC in general and I want to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about Backbone.js is that a model instance can exist in multiple collections at the same time, thus, when one model updates in 1 collection, the same instance gets updated in the other collection firing the events for both collections and both models.

what this means is that you should and could create a 'global' UsersCollection on your application scope, into which you push all instances of users.

```
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var userCollection = new UserCollection();
    userCollection.update([models], {remove: false});
```

next time you initialize a second UserCollection, you could add a method on the 'parse' method to get-or-fetch the model instance in the global usersCollection, so that you don't instantiate a model with the same id twice.

I would keep the collections separate from eachother as each collection might have a different comparator attached to it. Imagine one view of users listed alphabetically (friends) and one list of users listed by another state.

Play around with the power of single instances of models in multiple collections, try to keep the models in sync through a global collection. That would be my way forward.

Comment: Thank you!! So you mean 1 model (user) one view (list of users) and various collections (friends, followers, searchResult, following etc.)?

Comment: yes, try to have the same model instance for 1 particular user the same in each collection, for each collection have a corresponding view.